# How to add level2 predictors in multilevel regression (package nlme)

Tags: r, multi-level, nlme

I have a question concerning multi level regression models in R, specifically how to add predictors for my level 2 "measure".

Please consider the following example (this is not a real dataset, so the values might not make much sense in reality):

```
date        id    count    bmi    poll
2012-08-05  1     3        20.5   1500
2012-08-06  1     2        20.5   1400
2012-08-05  2     0        23     1500
2012-08-06  2     3        23     1400
```

The data contains

- different persons ("id"...so it's two persons)
- the body mass index of each person ("bmi", so it doesn't vary within an id)
- the number of heart problems each person has on a specific day ("count). So person 1 had three problems on August the 5th, whereas person 2 had no difficulties/problems on that day
- the amount of pollutants (like Ozon or sulfit dioxide) which have been measured on that given day

My general research question is, if the amount of pollutants effects the numer of heart problems in the population.
In a first step, this could be a simple linear regression:
    lm(count ~ poll)

However, my data for each day is so to say clustered within persons. I have two measures from person 1 and two measures from person 2.

So my basic idea was to set up a multilevel model with persons (id) as my level 2 variable.

I used the nlme package for this analysis:

```
lme(fixed=count ~ poll, random = ~poll|id, ...)
```

No problems so far.

However, the true influence on level 2 might not only come from the fact that I have different persons. Rather it would be much more likely that the effect WITHIN a person might come from his or her bmi (and many other person related variables, like age, amount of smoking and so on).

To make a longstory short:

**How can I specify such level two predictors in the lme function?**

Or in other words: How can I setup a model, where the relationship between heart problems and pollution is different/clustered/moderated by the body mass index of a person (and as I said maybe additionally by this person's amount of smoking or age)

Unfortunately, I don't have a clue, how to tell R, what I want. I know oif other software (one of them called *HLM*), which is capable of doing waht I want, but I'm quite sure that R can this as well...

So, many thanks for any help!

deschen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you do not have to, as long as you correctly specify random effects. The `lme` function automatically detects which variables are level 1 or 2. Consider this example using `Oxboys` where each subject was measured 9 times. For the time being, let me use `lmer` in the `lme4` package.

```
library(nlme)
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

Oxboys %>%                                                #1
  filter(as.numeric(Subject)<25) %>%                      #2
  mutate(Group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=72)) %>%            #3
  lmer(height ~ Occasion*Group + (1|Subject), data=.) %>% #4     
  anova()                                                 #5
```

Here I am picking 24 subjects (#2) and arranging them into 3 groups (#3) to make this data balanced.  Now the design of this study is a split-plot design with a repeated-measures factor (Occasion) with q=9 levels and a between-subject factor (Group) with p=3 levels. Each group has n=8 subjects. Occasion is a level-1 variable while Group is level 2.

In #4, I did not specify which variable is level 1 or 2, but `lmer` gives you correct output. How do I know it is correct? Let us check the multi-level model's degrees of freedom for the fixed effects. If your data is balanced, the Kenward–Roger approximation used in the `lmerTest` will give you exact dfs and F/t-ratios [according to this article](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/vignettes/pbkrtest-introduction.pdf). That is, in this example dfs for the test of Group, Occasion, and their interaction should be p-1=2, q-1=8, and (p-1)*(q-1)=16, respectively. The df for the Subject error term is (n-1)p = 21 and the df for the Subject:Occasion error term is p(n-1)(q-1)=168. In fact, these are the "exact" values we get from the `anova` output (#5).

I do not know what algorithm `lme` uses for approximating dfs, but `lme` does give you the same dfs. So I am assuming that it is accurate.

Comment: Well, thanks for that answer, which helps me very much. I'll try it tomorrow using the suggested lme4 package.

Comment: I've now tried to build up a multilevel model with lmer package. However, I'm a little bit stuck in specifying, which is a random and which a fixed effect (honestly, I never fully understood the concepts). To stay with my example: if _id_ contains my participants and _bmi_ is constant across these persons (ids), is that a fixed or random effect? Same for my pollutants (_poll_). They vary each day and are on level 1. So is this a random or fixed effect?

Comment: That's very a nuanced issue. I cannot tell you since I do not have sufficient information about your design/purpose of your study. You may want to check [this post out](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode). I am assuming that you are a researcher, not a statistician. Then my best advice would be this: follow what people do in your discipline, unless you are willing to argue otherwise.

Comment: You're right. And I've already found this post and followed the links. The problem is mostly due to the fact that there are many definitions of random/fixed and it is sometimes difficult to translate the regarding definitions for the purposes of the own study. In my example above I would say that _bmi_ is a random effect, because one can say that the _bmi_-values are a random sample from the population. However, the pollutants (_poll_), which have been measured throughout the year, would be IMO fixed effects, because we have the complete measures of the year, not just a sort of random sample.